# When or where UITableViewCell finished layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, layout

I created cell by:

```
cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: identifier1)
```

I know the default init size is `(320,44)`. I set the height is 80.0

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80.0
    }
```

**So question is when the cell was layout(Change from 44 to 80)?** even i called `layoutIfNeeded`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: identifier1)
       }
        print(cell.frame) // (0,0,320,44)
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        print(cell.frame) // still (0,0,320,44)

        return cell 
}
```

Comment: You cannot trust the height in the frame in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Is the table cell view actually 44 height when it loads?

Comment: @rocky sorry, i think your comment make no scene. thank you!

Comment: The height will change to 80 when NSTableViewDelegate:heightForRowAtIndexPath is called.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are printing `cell.frame` immediately after creating the cell, it takes the default height of 44. It will use the height from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` when is renders the table.

When you call `setNeedsLayout` is made, it set a flag and the changes would be rendered during the next render cycle. You cannot expect it to immediately reflect in next statement.

From Apple documentation:

> Call this method on your application’s main thread when you want to adjust the layout of a view’s subviews. This method makes a note of the request and returns immediately. Because this method does not force an immediate update, but instead waits for the next update cycle, you can use it to invalidate the layout of multiple views before any of those views are updated. This behavior allows you to consolidate all of your layout updates to one update cycle, which is usually better for performance.